# designing a platform...or an API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I am thinking of building a little reminder app. I want it to be usable across a variety of medium (irc, email, command line, web) and was thinking about how I would design such a thing without the use of lots of duct tape.

So, for example "remind me to take out the trash in 20 minutes" would be one thing a user could submit. This would then go and remind the person in 20 minutes, using the submitted medium if available and a default medium otherwise (such as email).

So, I'm not quite sure what would be a good way to design this. Obviously I feel some things like email vs irc will need different logic and will need to be implemented separately, but I feel otherwise there's a solid core that I want to flesh out that I can extend in a variety of ways. I just don't know how to design such a thing or what a good model would be.

I'm a RoR developer and would be building it in ruby.

So, what would be a good way to approach this? recommended reading... similar questions... I'm trying to gain direction on implementing this but am not sure where to look. This WOULD be basically an API no? (obviously never made one before)

Comment: Probably your best bet is to implement a REST service and then add services on top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a neat idea! Here are some resources I thought would be helpful.

Whenever you have a lot of different services interacting directly with your service, by far the *easiest* (and most sane, in my opinion) way of accomplishing this is by creating a REST service. IRC, web, command line — all of these can interact with a RESTful interface.

Rails is RESTful by default, so just by using standard Rails conventions, you can a nice standard RESTful API.

Additionally, there are many libraries on Github written in Ruby that make interacting with IRC and creating command line utilities very easy.

As for email, the easiest way is to use a service (such as [Mailgun](http://mailgun.com)). With Mailgun, you can create email addresses (such as remind_me@reminderapp.com) at which you can receive mail. Mailgun does all the heavy lifting to receive the email and parse it out, and can send it directly to an API endpoint in your application. See [their documentation](http://documentation.mailgun.net/user_manual.html#receiving-messages) for more information. (It's important to note that there are other services, such as [Send Grid](http://sendgrid.com) that also provide inbound mail processing. I've used many, and Mailgun is my recommendation.)

I'd also recommend setting up a job queue to process the inbound creation of reminders and outbound notifications. [Resque](https://github.com/defunkt/resque) is by far the best library written in Ruby (though [Sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq) is an interesting new alternative that I've enjoyed using). There are several plugins for Resque, such as [resque_mailer](https://github.com/zapnap/resque_mailer) that make sending out emails very easily. You can also use [resque_scheduler](https://github.com/bvandenbos/resque-scheduler) to schedule notifications to be delivered in the future (like, as in your example, in 20 minutes).

If you're interested in sending out SMS notifications as well, I'd check out [Twilio](http://www.twilio.com/) or [Moonshado](http://moonshado.com/). A free solution is to use the carriers' email to SMS gateways, but in general deliverability is an issue with these. [SMS-fu](https://github.com/brendanlim/sms-fu) is a good (but old) gem for this, but you can also just find a list [online](http://www.mutube.com/projects/open-email-to-sms/gateway-list/) and do it yourself.

You should also look into [Chronic](https://github.com/mojombo/chronic), which is an awesome natural language parser for dates and times (which can help you parse at 'in 20 minutes', for example).

Hope this helps!

Comment: (i hate comments on this site)  all exactly what I had in mind as far as parts go. what I'm confused on I guess is how I can submit "any old string" and have it route to the correct action to parse and act on. For example, "remind me to take out the trash in 20 minutes" would go to the "remind" function where as "order me 2 more toilet paper" goes to the order action. I understand REST and CRUD but I guess i'm befuzzled because there's all this extra logic that i'll have to implement and i'm not sure where it goes or how data enters the application or what have you.

Comment: I'd route it all to one controller action. You can move the complicated parsing into a lib class and just call it in the controller, so you can keep your controller clean. But yes, there will be a lot of extra logic. Sounds like fun!

Comment: ok, thank you, thats helpful. I was thinking i'd have to have all these other controllers somehow but yes i like the idea of doing it as a lib and just passing it off to that. I was thinking something like this might be a good case for something noSQL, but I don't know what that's like with rails. Anyway, thanks!

Comment: Yeah, I think keeping it in one controller will make the API easier to consume as well, so compiling a command line utility or an IRC library would be much easier. As for as noSQL, I love Redis. The EXPIRE/TTL command would be especially helpful here. Good luck!